# how to get the real unix timestamp in java

Tags: java, android, unix, timestamp

When I use `new Data().getTime();` with java in android, I can get the long value(13bits like 143XXXXX...XX), this value is determinded by the local time, when i change my android device local time, such as in advance or delay some hours, this value will be changed. How can I get the real unix timestamp disregard the local time and without using the network? thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just changing the timezone, `System.currentTimeMillis()` will get the UTC time for you just fine. If you're futzing with system clock inaccuracies (for example, setting your clock faster ten minutes or something), afaik `System.currentTimeMillis()` will increase by 10 minutes correspondingly. The only way to get an accurate time would be to get a response from a time server and check against that. I like `time.nist.gov` myself.

Answer (score 1):

what you probably want is

```
Systen.currentTimeMillis()
```

it returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

What you are lookinh for is `System.currentTimeMillis()`

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)